# TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len() python

Tags: python, csv, typeerror

I keep getting this error

```
TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()
```

here is the code:

```
def main():
    myList = [ ]
    myList = read_csv()
    ## myList = showList(myList)
    searchList = searchQueryForm(myList)
    if len(searchList) == 0:
        print("I have nothing to print")
    else:
        showList(searchList)
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include the relevant parts of `read_csv` and `searchQueryForm(myList)`.

Comment: Probably `searchQueryForm()` is missing return statement. And please fix indentation.

Comment: yes. `searchQueryForm()` function return `None` value,

Answer (score 7):

`searchQueryForm` apparently returns a `None` if it finds nothing. Since you can't apply `len` to `None`, you'll have to check for that explicitly:

```
if searchList is None or len(searchList) == 0:
```

Answer (score 2):

The object which you want to get the `len()` from is obviously a `None` object.

It is the `searchList`, returned from `searchQueryForm(myList)`.

So this is `None` when it shouldn't be.

Either fix that function or live with the fact that it can return `None`:

```
if len(searchlist or ()) == 0:
```

or

```
if not searchlist:
```

Answer (score 0):

The `searchQueryForm()` function return `None` value and `len()` in-build function not accept None type argument. So Raise `TypeError` exception.

**Demo**:

```
>>> searchList = None
>>> print type(searchList)
<type 'NoneType'>
>>> len(searchList)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()
```

Add one more condition in if loop to check `searchList` is `None` or not

**Demo**:

```
>>> if searchList==None or len(searchList) == 0:
...   print "nNothing"
... 
nNothing
```

**return** statement is missing in the `searchQueryForm()` function when code is not go into last `if loop`. By **default** `None` value is return when we not return any specific value from function.

```
def searchQueryForm(alist):
    noforms = int(input(" how many forms do you want to search for? "))
    for i in range(noforms):
        searchQuery = [ ]
        nofound = 0 ## no found set at 0
        formname = input("pls enter a formname >> ") ## asks user for formname
        formname = formname.lower() ## converts to lower case
        for row in alist:
            if row[1].lower() == formname: ## formname appears in row2
                searchQuery.append(row) ## appends results
                nofound = nofound + 1 ## increments variable
                if nofound == 0:
                    print("there were no matches")
                    return searchQuery
    return []
   # ^^^^^^^    This was missing
```